# How to use nested index in RavenDB

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I have a chat object with participants as a list. I need to enhance the participants' records with further metadata (eg. fullname, company name, instead of just the user ids).

UPDATE:
**ChatLastMessage_Index**: is queried only by passing an ExternalChatId or a participantId (hence find a specific chat or all the chats for a specific participant)

**Profile_Index**: is queried passing a person's name

The goal here would be to *decorate* the chat's participants with the persons' metadata.
Currently the index used to retrieve a chat and its last message is:

```
public class ChatLastMessage_Index : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ChatMessage, ChatLastMessage_Index.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ExternalChatId { get; set; }
        public List<Participant> Participants { get; set; }

        // last message's information:
        public string LastMessageUuid { get; set; }
    }

    public ChatLastMessage_Index()
    {
        Map = messages => from message in messages
                          let chat = LoadDocument<Chat>(message.ChatId)
                          select new Result
                          {
                              Id = chat.Id,
                              ExternalChatId = chat.ExternalChatId,
                              Participants = chat.Participants,
                              LastMessageUuid = message.Id,
                              LastMessageCreatedBy = message.CreatedBy
                          };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.ExternalChatId into g
                            select new Result
                            {
                                Id = g.First().Id,
                                ExternalChatId = g.First().ExternalChatId,
                                Participants = g.First().Participants,
                                LastMessageUuid = g.OrderByDescending(m => m.LastMessageCreatedAt).First().LastMessageUuid
                            };
    }
}
```

As we have another index (Profile_Index) that retrieves all the participants metadata needed, I was wondering whether would it be possible to re use its results inside the ChatLastMessage_Index in order to avoid having to copy/paste its logic.

Below the second index used to retrieve the participants metadata:

```
public class Profile_Index : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<PersonProfile_Index.ReducedResult>
{
    public class ReducedResult
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
        public string OrgCountryName { get; set; }
        public List<LanguageProficiency> Languages { get; set; }
    }

    public PersonProfile_Index()
    {
        AddMap<Person>(
            persons => from person in persons
                       select new ReducedResult
                       {
                           Id = person.Id,
                           Name = person.Name,
                           Languages = person.Languages,
                           ProfileImageUrl = person.ProfileImage.Url
                           JobTitle = null,
                           OrganizationId = null,
                           OrganizationName = null,
                           OrgCountryName = null
                       });

        AddMap<Employment>(
           employments => from empl in employments
                          let org = LoadDocument<Organization>(empl.OrganizationId)
                          let countryName = LoadDocument<Country>(org.CountryOfResidenceId).Name
                          select new ReducedResult
                          {
                              Id = empl.PersonId,
                              Name = null,
                              Languages = null, 
                              ProfileImageUrl = null,
                              JobTitle = empl.JobTitle,
                              OrganizationId = org.Id,
                              OrganizationName = org.Name,
                              OrgCountryName = countryName
                          });

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Id into g
                            select new ReducedResult
                                   {
                                       Id = g.Key,
                                       Name = g.Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault(p => p != null),
                                       JobTitle = g.Select(x => x.JobTitle).FirstOrDefault(p => p != null),
                                       Languages = g.Select(x => x.Languages).FirstOrDefault(p => p != null),
                                       ProfileImageUrl = g.Select(x => x.ProfileImageUrl).FirstOrDefault(p => p != null),
                                       OrganizationId = g.Select(x => x.OrganizationId).FirstOrDefault(p => p != null),
                                       OrganizationName = g.Select(x => x.OrganizationName).FirstOrDefault(p => p != null),
                                       OrgCountryName = g.Select(x => x.OrgCountryName).FirstOrDefault(p => p != null)
                                   };

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to query on this "further metadata" as well or is it only for display purposes? If it's only for display purposes it might be solved with result transformers. Could you update your post and show your queries as well?

Comment: Thanks Jens. I updated the question. Indeed a Transformer could be a solution, but I am a bit concerned about eventual costs it introduces. I mean the cost for "building" the results at each query (with the Transformer) compared to the cost due to the index update (in case I would enhance the Chat index)

Comment: How many results do you think your query will return? The transformer will work for each result when you request it and if you aren't trying to return thousands records, I'd say you only map the properties you query on (ExternalChatId / ParticipantId) and then transform the result you want. We map/reduced just like this a lot before, but changed almost everything to use result transformers instead. It, as always, depends a bit on your scenario, but the indexing engine will thank you...

Comment: The Chat index embeds the logic to return the last message (avoiding having to evaluate that via query or other logic). Therefore an index would be preferred in this case. As far as I know I cannot use a TransformResult inside an indexes.